# View not rendered when passing model from different controller spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

I am having two controllers which return the same view with different models,

the first controller is,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getusersPage(ModelMap model)
    {

        try{

            //Some logic to create usr object
            model.addAttribute("users",usr);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "users";
    }
```

The second one,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/users/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String searchUser(ModelMap model,@RequestParam("usersname") String name)
    {

         //Some logic to create usr object
        model.addAttribute("users",users);
        return "users";

    }
```

The first controller is working and the view is rendered properly with data. But when second controller gets hit, the data is loaded but without css.

[View returned by second controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAJg6.png)

Comment: Please post your `view`

Comment: It is working if I change the url request from /users/search to /usersearch in the controller's requestmapping. But what might be the reason?